# Point the fallacy in the following inequality.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, logarithms, functional-inequalities

> Find the integers which do not satisfy the inequality $\log_{1/2}(x+5)^2>\log_{1/2}(3x-1)^2$.

When I did this expanding the squares I got:

$x^2-2x-3>0\implies (x-3)(x+1)>0\implies x\epsilon(-\infty,-1)\cup(3,\infty)$

Also from domain $x\neq-5,\frac{1}{3}$. Hence answer is $6$.

But when I did use the property of $\log$ as follows:

$\log_{1/2}(x+5)^2>\log_{1/2}(3x-1)^2\implies \log_{1/2}(x+5)>\log_{1/2}(3x-1)\implies x+5<3x-1\implies x>3$

What concepts I'm lacking please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$(x+5)^2\geq(3x-1)^2$$ or
$$(x-3)(x+1)\leq0,$$
which gives $-1\leq x\leq3$ and we get the answer $\{-1,0,1,2,3,-5\}$.

I solved it in integer numbers, which you wanted.

You can't cancel squares by your way because $$\log_ax^2=2\log_{a}|x|$$

By this way we need to solve
$$|x+5|\geq|3x-1|,$$
which gives the same answer.

Another way to explain.

With domain $x\neq-5$ and $x\neq-\frac{1}{3}$ we obtain:
$$\log_{\frac{1}{2}}(x+5)^2>\log_{\frac{1}{2}}(3x-1)^2\Leftrightarrow$$
$$\Leftrightarrow2|x+5|<2|3x+1|.$$

Since we not need satisfy, we obtain:
$$|x+5|\geq|3x-1|$$
and with $x=-5$ we get the answer.

Comment: @mnulb What do you think about my solution?

Comment: I think as I wrote *not satisfy*, instead of taking complement you solved reversing the sign of inequality, am I correct? (your answer is correct)
But I need to know why we can't cancel squares using logarithmic properties?

Comment: @mnulb Since $0<\frac{1}{2}<1$ for "not satisfy" we need $(x+5)^2\geq(3x-1)^2$.

Comment: @mnulb I fixed my post. See now.